# addEventListener is not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

i use the postMessage function to send a message to a iframe in my page like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
)};//test is the id of my iframe in a.html
```

and in b.html,i use `window.addEventListener('message', onmessage, false);`to receiver this message:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var onmessage = function(e) { 
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = e.data; 
    }; 
    window.addEventListener('message', onmessage, false); 
}; //this is the javascript in b.html
```

it works well in `IE10`,but i can't receive any message in `chrome` and `firefox`!why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).ready` will run on `DOMContentLoaded`, which can happen before the subframe is done loading.  So there is a good chance you're sending the message in the parent before you've added the listener in the child.

Comment: So,what should i do to send message correctly in `chrome` and `firefox`?And it can work in IE10,could you plz tell me why?

Comment: it's the reason.i don't know the `load()` function before.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your code in window.onload ,maybe when you call postMessage,iframe onload has not been triggered

```
 var onmessage = function(e) { 
        console.log(e);
    };
if ( typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
            window.addEventListener('message', onmessage, false);
          } else if ( typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') {
            window.attachEvent('onmessage', onmessage);
          }
```

Comment: i tried it , but ... it still can't receive anything.and in `IE10`,`type of window.addEventListener` is always a `function`.

Comment: IE10 and IE11 support W3C event model so they have addEventListener  method.You put html files in http server or just open it by broswer?

Comment: just open it by broswer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Chrome and FireFox Update if the browser are latest.

OR

try....

```
 alert(onmessage);
```

if their any message output.

Comment: yes my browser is the latest.and `alert(onmessage)`?`onmessage`is just a function.

Comment: if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
     else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

Comment: copy the code above this. this is checking the browser to fit your code